Laravel Pest tests with RefreshDatabase trait not refreshing database
With Laravel feature tests using Pest, despite using the RefreshDatabase trait, my SQLite database isn't refreshed between test executions. This causes test failures because of persisted data from previous tests.
I'm using SQLite 3.37.2. Application is correctly rolling back transactions after each test (Illuminate\\Database\\Concerns\\ManagesTransactions:309 $pdo-\>rollBack() returning true). Models created during tests are still in the database after the test suite runs.
Code:
it('test1', function () {
    Testmodel::create(['foo' => 'bar');
    expect(Testmodel::count())->toBe(1);  // this test succeeds
});

it('test2', function () {
    expect(Testmodel::count())->toBe(0); // this test fails
});

Am I misunderstanding how RefreshDatabase works with SQLite? Why isn't the data cleared despite successful transaction rollbacks?

It should be cleared completely
